# Mysql like regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

Hi there here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `person` 
WHERE memo LIKE  'John Smith %'
OR memo LIKE  '% John Smith %'
OR memo LIKE  '% John % Smith %'
OR memo LIKE  '%John%Smith%'
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN memo LIKE  'John Smith %'
THEN 1 
WHEN memo LIKE  '% John Smith %'
THEN 2 
WHEN memo LIKE  '% John % Smith %'
THEN 3
WHEN memo LIKE  '%John%Smith%'
THEN 4
ELSE 5
END
```

how to convert to not use the `OR` operator

can be regexps?

Comment: You want to select John smith from the memo column?

Comment: You have a lot of redundant rules. For example, if `memo LIKE 'John Smith %'` is true, then certainly `memo LIKE '%John%Smith%' is true. If you are wanting to order depending upon how much "white space" is around the names `John` and `Smith` (which is what your code appears to be attempting), then you'll need to keep the separate rules in the `CASE`, but you can reduce the rules in the selection. If you stated in words exactly what you're trying to accomplish, then you can get better assistance.

Comment: I need to get all the rows where the contained
- Substring 'john smith' (John Smith loren ipsum)
- Substring 'john' and substring 'smith' (Loren john ipsum smith)
- Substring 'john' and substring 'smith' is not an exact match (Loren eljohnatan ipsum dolar lismithlums)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `where` just to:

```
WHERE memo LIKE '%John%Smith%'
```

The other conditions are redundant.

As for the `order by`, there probably isn't any way to simplify that.

Comment: I need to get all the rows where the contained - Substring 'john smith' (John Smith loren ipsum) - Substring 'john' and substring 'smith' (Loren john ipsum smith) - Substring 'john' and substring 'smith' is not an exact match (Loren eljohnatan ipsum dolar lismithlums)

Comment: @pavelchervov . . . That is what this `where` clause does.  `%` is a wildcard that matches zero or more characters.